# Check if image exist, The value of variable not change

Tags: javascript, image, variables, onload

This code checks if exist a image or not.

Inside the function onload I would like to change the variable 'control' with a boolean value.

```
var control = 'a.jpg';
var image_name = control;
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
    control = true; // Why this change does not happen outside of this function?
};
image.onerror = function() {
    control = false; // Why this change does not happen outside of this function?
};
image.src = image_name;

console.log(control); // The value is not changed in a boolean
```

But outside the function, the variable is not changed. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function image.onload only execute after loading the images, it may take 500-1200ms execute,

`console.log(control);`   executing before loading the image thats why alway shown as false

**try to print the control value after few sec delay**

```
var control = 'a.jpg';
var image_name = control;
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
    control = true; // Why this change does not happen outside of this function?
};
image.onerror = function() {
    control = false; // Why this change does not happen outside of this function?
};
image.src = image_name;
setTimeout(function(){ 
console.log(control); // its work
},2000);
```

Change your code structure like this

```
var control = 'a.jpg';
var image_name = control;
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
    control = true; 
    nextProcess();
};
image.onerror = function() {
    control = false; 
    nextProcess();
};
image.src = image_name;
function nextProcess(){
  console.log(control);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `console.log(control);` is called before the `onload` or `onerror` functions of `image` are called.

The `control` variable changes but you call the `log` before it changes. You can modify your code to something like this in order to achieve what you want:

```
var control = 'a.jpg';
var image_name = control;
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
    control = true;
    after();
};
image.onerror = function() {        
    control = false;
    after();
};
image.src = image_name;

function after(){
    alert(control);
    console.log(control);
}
```

You can also check it in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9bz7rms/).